# R: From index matrix to matrix with names

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix of indexes referencing a vector with names. (as a result of nearest neighbor search)
There are 0s in the matrix (no neighbor found in radius) I want to replace the index with the actual names. What would be an easy way to do this?

Tamas

Comment: Hey Tamas :-), welcome to SO. You're using the R-Tag, so let us look at it together, I'll mark the important spots: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks**. For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps you:

data:

```
set.seed(1337)
m <- matrix(sample(c(0,0,0,1:5), 25, TRUE), 5, 5)
```

looks like:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    2    0    5    0    4
#[2,]    2    5    5    5    3
#[3,]    0    0    4    5    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    5    0    2
```

names vector:

```
namesVec <- c(0,paste0("name_",1:5))
```

code:

```
m[] <- namesVec[c(m) + 1]
```

result looks like:

```
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
#[1,] "name_2" "0"      "name_5" "0"      "name_4"
#[2,] "name_2" "name_5" "name_5" "name_5" "name_3"
#[3,] "0"      "0"      "name_4" "name_5" "0"     
#[4,] "name_1" "0"      "0"      "0"      "0"     
#[5,] "0"      "0"      "name_5" "0"      "name_2"
```